# springmvc how to fetch the parameter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In spring I have the url:--

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMvc/viewdetail/id?key=1
```

I want to fetch the **"key"** value

So,I have done:--

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/viewdetail/id",method=RequestMethod.GET, 
 params={"key"})

         public  @ResponseBody String viewDetail11(Map<String, Object> map,    
 HttpServletRequest request,
@RequestParam(value = "key") int key) throws IOException{

    detailservice.detail(key);

    return "viewdetail";
    }
```

But,with this code I am not getting any value.why?

Answer (score 1):

With the same code in my local machine, the value of key is successfully retrieved. Can you please share your web.xml, Full controller class and spring version you are using?

Comment: Yes..you were right..I had a problem in web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this, only slight modification:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewdetail/id",method=RequestMethod.GET)

   public  @ResponseBody String viewDetail11(Map<String, Object> map,   
     HttpServletRequest request,  @RequestParam("key") int key) throws IOException {

        detailservice.detail(key);

        return "viewdetail";
    }
```

NOTE: If this doesn't work confirm the following:

- param is appearing in url
- no exceptions are being thrown (very important as it may not be binding properly)